# How to add acronym list

Tags: glossaries

I want to add an list of acronyms that I can reference to continously in the text.

Say if I write in the glossary `\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}` NY will appear in the document when I type `\gls{ny}`.

I have the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

And inside the document where i want to place the list i type:

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]

\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
```

But only NY appears in the acronym list and it has a 1 after it:

```
NY New York. 1
```

But i want it to be:

```
NY New York
```

Neither LA nor UN appears in the list even if I write them in the text. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article} % Load the package 
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries
\begin{document} 

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]

 % abbreviations: 
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un} {UN}{United Nations}

\gls{ny}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post the document, not just fragments. You should **not** use `\newacronym` after `\printglossary`, however. Better define the acronyms in the preamble!

Comment: My document is really big, I cant post everything here. The usepackage part is inside a settings.tex file and the useacronym part is inside a acronym.tex file that is \input in the main.tex.

Comment: Then try to reduce the document (which is the usual procedure here ;-))

Comment: \documentclass{article}
 
% Load the package
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
 
\begin{document}
 
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]

% abbreviations:

\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}


\gls{ny}
 
\end{document}

Comment: Well, you don't use `\gls{LA}` and `\gls{un}` -- unless you specify `\glsaddall` only `ny` will be printed.

Comment: It does seem to indicate that an entry is created if `\printglossary` is between `\newacronym` and `\gls`. Might be a misprint though, consider investigating on that. (If it's even still relevant, anyway.)

Comment: Check out the following link, it will automatically creates acronym list. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/automatic-acronym-list-in-latex/dzvxfzpsjrmm

Answer (score 11):

No `\gls{foo}` or `\glsaddall` → no displayed glossary entry for this key.

Use `nonumberlist` to suppress the page number at the end of the displayed glossary entry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries


\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}


\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: NY only appears still. The number is gone.

Comment: @Bob1990: Well, then something is wrong with your code that is not shown, however. As I said in the comments above: Do not use **\newacronym** in the document body, perhaps that's the cause. As you can see from my screen shot, the code I posted works. (Using TL 2015 (frozen state) on Linux

Comment: I tried to put \newacronym outside the document body but it didn't help. I am clueless right now. It is strange that it doesn't work, it should be easy to fix.

Comment: @Bob1990: Do you really have `\gls{la}` etc. too?

Comment: Even if i write out \gls{la} or not it does not matter. LA will not appear in the list, only NY. NY always appears no matter what.

Comment: @Bob1990: There's nothing I can do with invisible code -- sorry.

Answer (score 4):

> It works for me!!!!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}[ NY]  
\acro { NY }        New York
\acro { LA }        Los Angeles
\acro { UN }        United Nations    
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: this package is much better. BTW how to add a title?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be using `nopostdot` as option

`\usepackage[acronym,nopostdot]{glossaries}`

The reason only NY shows up in your Acronyms list is that you didn't use LA  or UN with the `\gls{}` command.
`\glsaddall` also mentions unused glossary entries